# TableViewCell: dequeued cell is not an instance of cell with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've set a UITableView in a Custom UIViewController which I've called SavingViewController. I've set the delegate and the datasource for the tableView to SavingViewController, and I believe I've set all of the Identifiers in the storyboard correctly, but the fatal error in the guard statement is always called

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "WishlistTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? WishlistTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of WishlistTableViewCell.")
    }

    return cell
}
```

[Restoration ID is set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpXNm.png)

[As is the TableViewCell Identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEEcc.png)

------ Full Code -------

```
import UIKit

class SavingViewController: UIViewController {
    var totalSavings: Double = 0

    var items: [WishListItem] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var savingsView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var wishlistView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var wishlistTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var savingsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        items = DummyPurchaseData.returnDummyItemsArray()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "WishlistTableViewCell")

        tableView.reloadData()

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addWishButton(_:)))
        let editButton = editButtonItem
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil);
        toolbar.items = [editButton, flexibleSpace, addButton]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func addWishButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        //addWish()
        print("Do nothing")
    }

    func addItemToWishlist(item: WishListItem) {
        items.append(item)
    }

}

extension SavingViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "WishlistTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? WishlistTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of WishlistTableViewCell.")
        }

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of this line-:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "WishlistTableViewCell")
```

You are working with **interface builder** not doing it programmatically. Remove this and it will work .

Answer (score 0):

Istead of

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
               forCellReuseIdentifier: "WishlistTableViewCell")
```

you should have:

```
tableView.register(WishlistTableViewCell.self,
               forCellReuseIdentifier: "WishlistTableViewCell")
```